# How to insert data into destination table without having any primary key in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I am using talend for ETL I don't have enough experience in this, I am having two tables for example- `account` and `account_roles` account table is having id, name, password etc fields and account_roles table is having `account_id` which is f.k to account table's pk. and one more field.
Both the fields in account_roles are having duplicates, I want to save account_roles in destination with `update` and `insert` logic using talend.
But I am getting error as I don't have any table that can be treated as primary key in the account_roles table, so talend can't update or insert it.

How I deal with this situation I tried tDBOutput advance option `use_field_option` but still it requires unique entries.
Is there any possible solution to this issue, I also want to know if I can make table Foreign key in the account_roles table will it work then? If yes then How to make F.k in talend OPen studio is my second question.

Attaching Snapshots of my tables and tMap below -
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to know the way I can put my tables into database if I don't have any primary key! Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

#### First question

I think you should place the primary key in the physical `account_roles` table. Talend will use the key indication of the `dbOutput` component, and the physical key of the table.

In order to delete duplicates rows, you can also use a `tUniqRow` before the `dbOutput`: The key you indicate in the `UniqRow` is not directly linked to the database; this is only the key on which `tUniqRow` will be based.

#### Second question

It's not possible to delegate the f.k. verification to Talend. But you can do this verification in your database by placing foreign keys in your table. If an `id` is not present in the reference table, the database returns an error that is returned by Talend.